# how to install Joobsbox on wampserver

Tags: wampserver

how to install Joobsbox on wamp server (Without db password....)

this field be empty received this message 
"Joobsbox really needs a database. Please let it have one."

please help me
thank you

Answer (score 0):

1. Read the documentation
2. Make sure you have the PDO extension enabled (it is by default on newer versions of WampServer)
3. Check the database credentials and other config values are correct in `config/config.ini.php`
4. Try creating the database first (phpMyAdmin is usually installed by default, alternatively I like to use [MySQL Workbench](http://www.mysql.com/products/workbench/)